# What LORE and TODO_LORE stand for in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, task, todo

I've noticed that in eclipse (Luna), in the Task view, in the filter, it is possible filter by TODO, FIXME, LORE and TODO_LORE.
What LORE and TODO_LORE are used for?

UPDATE I mean, what is the use of these tags? the use of  TODO and FIXME are clear to me.

Comment: In Eclipse you can add custom task tags. Go to Preferences, search for task. Now you can add `FIXME_LORE` as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer, didnt know that you can edit these value in eclipse. I'm asking when use the tags LORE and TODO_LORE in code

Comment: Ask the person who created these tags. :) They are not default at least not in ee eclipse package.